# JS element event, refresh the element

Tags: javascript

If for example I have the next event:

```
document.getElementById('TagSearchInput').onkeyup = function(e)
{
     //Code...
}
```

Inside the event, there is a condition where I recreate the element (`TagSearchInput`). How can I refresh the event selector, from within the event?

Comment: What do you mean by `refresh the event selector`?

Comment: I want to tell it to find the same element, and reattach the event to it.

Comment: The code inside the event is about 400 lines.

Comment: Why do you need to recreate the element?

Comment: To move it (visually, between another two elements). I already tried CSS for the positioning, but this won't work, I need to actually place it between them.

Comment: You could insert the element in that two elements, that wont be difficult.

Comment: Have you tried moving it with the [`.appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.appendChild)? (I'm sure I'll be corrected if I'm wrong on this, but I think that should keep the existing event handler.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, ignoring any questions about why you'd be recreating the input...

Rather than using an anonymous function try something like this:

```
function TSIKeyupHandler(e)
{
     //Code...

     // within your condition where you want to re-attach the handler
     document.getElementById('TagSearchInput').onkeyup = TSIKeyupHandler;
}

document.getElementById('TagSearchInput').onkeyup = TSIKeyupHandler;
```

(Optionally put all of the above inside an immediately-invoked-anonymous-function if you want to keep the `TSIKeyupHandler()` function out of the global scope.)

Comment: Yep! That was what I was thinking of, and already tried it, but I forgot to add the 'e' argument in the caller function.